# Rotate pixel array 90 degrees in C++

Tags: c++, rotation, pixel

I've written the next function to rotate an unsigned char pixel array which holds a RGB image by 90 degrees. The problem I'm facing is that the rotated output is all completely garbled.

```
void rotate90(unsigned char *buffer, const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height)
{
    const unsigned int sizeBuffer = width * height * 3; 
    unsigned char *tempBuffer = new unsigned char[sizeBuffer];

    for (int y = 0, destinationColumn = height - 1; y < height; ++y, --destinationColumn)
    {
        int offset = y * width;

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            tempBuffer[(x * height) + destinationColumn] = buffer[offset + x];
        }
    }

    // Copy rotated pixels

    memcpy(buffer, tempBuffer, sizeBuffer);
    delete[] tempBuffer;
}
```

Comment: have you tried with a small array and worked out what the steps are by hand? that would be the best way to debug this kind of issue. In any event, since you don't know if you have a problem with the code or a problem with the actual logic, this would be a good place to start.

Comment: It seems that 3 bytes are used for one pixel.  It's only reflected in the allocation of `sizeBuffer`, but not anywhere else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace the line in the inner-most loop with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    tempBuffer[(x * height + destinationColumn) * 3 + i] = buffer[(offset + x) * 3 + i];
```

Answer (score 1):

this is merely C, add a cast to a temporary rgb type to let the compiler deal with pixel copy and offset computation :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

// buffer is interleaved RGB
void rotate90( unsigned char *buffer, const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height ) {
    struct rgb { unsigned char r_, g_, b_; };
    static_assert( sizeof( rgb ) == 3, "?" );

    size_t const count { width * height };

    auto source = reinterpret_cast<rgb*>( buffer );

    auto dest = std::unique_ptr<rgb[]>( new rgb[ count ] );

    for ( size_t y {}, destinationColumn = height - 1; y < height; ++y, --destinationColumn ) {
        size_t offset = y * width;
        for ( size_t x {}; x < width; x++ )
            dest[ ( x * height ) + destinationColumn ] = source[ offset + x ];
    }

    // Copy rotated pixels
    std::copy_n( dest.get(), count, source );
}
```

You should also look here for ideas on how to rotate by 90 degrees without a temporary storage and copy of the image size : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition